# Вопрос по MouseRightButtonDown

Tags: c#

Добрый день.

Разбираюсь в чужом коде, встретил такую конструкцию:

```
<b>ActiveTextElement.MouseRightButtonDown += something_MouseRightButtonDown;</b>
```

В другом же месте то же самое с минусом. Сейчас, по логике программы, после += гарантировано идёт -=.

Собственно, вопрос вот в чём: сейчас после добавления метода делегату гарантировано, что он оттуда уберётся. Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы было возможно проходить через код, где лежит += несколько раз, но при этом в делегате всегда был один метод. Подозреваю, что мне нужно что-то типа

```
<b>if (ActiveTextElement.MouseRightButtonDown.Count == 1)</b>
```

Ранее не встречался с подобными конструкциями. Подскажите, что тут можно сделать.

Comment: Используйте флаг и не морочьте себе голову. Вы не должны пытаться подглядеть во внутренности `MouseRightButtonDown`: там вполне могут быть чужие подписки.

Comment: Слона то я и не приметил. Пожалуй, это самый простой вариант.